# How to connect succesfully View, Controller and Model in a subdomain staging environment created in Cakephp?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, model-view-controller, path

We have created (the server hosting management and I) a subdomain staging environments (`staging.mysite.com`) from my main site for me to make changes over there instead of the original site. The staging is a exact copy of the main site.

The subdomain work fine when I make changes in the code like in the View files or in the Webroot folder like css or img files.

But the issues come when i make changes in the Controllers files or in the Model files, they don't connect with View folder, for example, and not changes can be done.

Notice that if I make changes in the Controllers and Models of the main domain code then the changes occur in both sites, main domains and in the subdomains as well.

Good to mention that the subdomain staging site connect perfectly to its own databse. If I register a member from the sign up page (staging page) it is well recorded in the database, for example.

The question is: How can I solve this issue? Where can the problem be located?

I had searched on internet, cakephp documents... I had changed the path on `webroot/index.php` according to cakephp documents, and nothing.

I'm new in cakephp and I'm learning it by myself solving issues and managing my two web platform.